# Template operator== overload test

Tags: c++, templates, comparison, operator-overloading

I am trying to write my very first typed `List` using linked lists in c++. The idea is to use it with some other modules I have done as part of an arduino library, so I am also trying to keep it small and efficient. All seems to work well up to the part where I added an `IndexOf` function which returns the index of the item provided. My problem is, how would I test if the value of the type in the list is equal to the value of the same type that was passed as an argument? Maybe its a long shot but could one compare them in memory, if they have the same values and same size, they must be the same...

Here is my class definition:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
private:              
    class node_t
    {
    public:
        T data;
        int index;
        node_t *next;
    };

    node_t *head;
    node_t *tail;

public:
    List();
    void Add(T data);              /** Adds object to end of list. */
    bool Contains(T data);         /** Returns true if list contains object. */
    int IndexOf(T data);           /** Returns the zero based index of first occurance. */
    void RemoveAt(int index);      /** Removes the item at index. */  
};

template <class T>
bool operator== (T val, T val2)
{
    return true;
}
```

I have overloaded the == operator, to perform this comparison but not sure how it could be done?

Comment: Did you by `template<class T> bool operator==(T val, T val2)` mean `template<class T> bool operator==(List<T> val, List<T> val2)`? The former can be any class, while the latter takes lists containing elements of any type. To compare, whether values are equal simply `a == b`. Also, (performance/intent) you should pass most data via `const &` (e.g. in `operator==()`, `Add`, `Contains`, `IndexOf`). Did I get the point wrong?

Comment: @nabijaczleweli: The idea is to use the former of the two implementations. I want to use it to compare any two similar classes which defines an item in the list and the one that it being compared to. I have tried `if (val1 == val2) return true; return false;` which compiles fine but causes the program to crash as soon as I use my custom class. Making the list of type `int` seems to work fine though. The    `const &` is new to me, I have read up on it and see that this is a highly debated constant reference but not sure how it would increase performance?

Comment: The former implementation defines an `operator==()` for *every* class (via templates), which you would need to supply. If you want to compare contained/passed instances of type `T` from the inside (functions) of `List` (which I understand is what you want to do), then do not do this. What you want to do is: say you have `T contained;` (acquired from internal linked structure) and `T data;` (as in `IndexOf()` function), just do `data == contained` or `contained == data` (depends on intent). Just that. All primitives and most(all?) STL classes have a "built-in" `operator==()`. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) You DO, on the other hand, need to supply custom `operator==()`s for your own classes.

Comment: I was thinking backwards and wanted my List to have the responsibility of comparing the types. Doesn't make any sense at all now that I think about it... so I followed your advice `data == contained` and implemented `operator==()` on my custom class and now it works like a charm! Thank you, I spent a couple of hours on this problem... noticed some other operators that are also in need of an operator overload. I know this is off the topic but I am still curious about the `const &`, I have also followed your advice there and used it anyway.

Comment: So, `const &` passes arguments by reference, not by copy, meaning that if your class is, say, 50 bytes big, and contains `std::vector`s, etc. and you pass by plain `T inst`, the copy constructor will be invoked, which is slow, needs to allocate memory, etc. It also won't work with move-only classes such as `std::unique_ptr`. If you pass by `const &`, however it's like you pass by pointer, except more elegant and safe: will not invoke copy-constructors, will work with EVERY class. Try searching "why pass by const & [c++]" on SO, maybe look at STL classes.